# Save data when the app is reinstalled

Tags: android

When you remove an application, user data is cleared. I want to save this information (such as user login). Is there any way to save data and restore them when the app is installed again?

Comment: Without writing your info to external SD or cloud storage?

Comment: You cab use backup service and store upto 5 mb of data on google cloud. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/keyvaluebackup.html

Comment: Yes. without external storage. 
You mean Android Service Backup?

Comment: It is done automatically when you enable it, since API 23 https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2015/10/android-6-0s-auto-backup-for-apps-perfect-data-backup-for-the-1-5/